# Dynamics CRM 2013 Chart DrillDown Sort

Tags: charts, dynamics-crm

Is there a way to sort a drill-down chart of a Dynamics CRM?

For example, I have two custom fields (X and Y) on a lead entity. I've already made a chart that use X and Y as the axis and already have them custom sorted.

However, there is a case when I want to drill-down chart X using Y field. If I do that I will get a drill-down Y chart **that is not custom sorted**.

Is there a way for me to **sort the drill-down Y chart**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is presumably not the answer you were hoping for: No, drill-down charts cannot really be customized.

I would suggest the following alternative solution:

1. Make a system chart showing the same values that is shown in the specific drill-down chart.
2. Apply custom sorting to this system chart, which you are aware is possible.
3. Have your users use this system chart instead of doing drill down. In this case they would first apply filtering to the view to show only the specific X values they are interested in. By then selecting your system chart, they will actually see the same data they would have by drilling down - only the data is sorted as intended.